# Trigonometry problem (related to the one I asked a few days ago but with one small change that makes a big difference!

Tags: trigonometry

Here is a new problem (same structure as the one I asked a few days ago, but the second fraction now has sine in the denominator rather than cosine and it seems to make a BIG difference)

> Eliminate $\theta$ from the expressions
>
> $$x^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{x \cos{3\theta}+y \sin{3\theta}}{\cos^{3}\theta} \tag1$$
> $$x^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{y \cos{3\theta}-x \sin{3\theta}}{\sin^{3}\theta} \tag2$$

Then, if possible find expressions for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\theta$

Solutions involving the substitution $t=\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}$ are likely possible, as are solutions involving complex numbers but I suspect a more "simple" solution just using trigonometric identities may be possible.

Like the previous question, I've worked on this for a few days and gotten not very far!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866216/eliminating-theta-from-x2y2-fracx-cos3-thetay-sin3-theta-cos3-theta?noredirect=1&lq=1   is this helps?

Comment: @Khosrotash - not really, that post is the one I modified to make this new problem.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in this problem, I can post a more complete solution.

The answers I was (eventually) able to work out are:

(i) $x^{2}+y^{2}=2-x$

(ii) $x=\frac{2+6\cos{4\theta}}{5+3\cos{4\theta}}$ and $y=\frac{6\sin{4\theta}}{5+3\cos{4\theta}}$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).